# JQuery está aparecendo somente valor de um input com .serialize()

Tags: jquery

Comecei a estudar JavaScript e JQuery. Estava fazendo um teste de exibir na tela o que era enviado via Form, mas está enviando valor somente de um campo, alguém teria como me ajudar?!

Aqui está o HTML com o script:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<form name="frm" id="frm" method="POST" action="">
   <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" value="" />
   <input type="text" name="sobrenome" id="sobrenome" value="" />
   <input type="submit" name="enviar" id="enviar" value="Enviar" />
</form>
<div id="exibir_valor"></div>
<script>
   $("#enviar").click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var valor = $("#frm").serialize();
     $.ajax({
       action: $(this),
       type:'POST',
       data: valor,
       url:'insert.php',
       success:function(data) {
         $( "#exibir_valor" ).html(data);
       }
     });
   });
</script>
```

e aqui o php só pra testar (insert.php):

```
<?php
  var_dump($name = $_POST['nome']);
  $last_name = $_POST['sobrenome'];
```

Desde já agradeço!

Comment: O seu código parece ok. Pode fazer alert, ou console.log de `valor` para ver o que tem lá? e no PHP você só está a fazer `var_dump` de um dos campos. Seria melhor fazer `var_dump($_POST);`. O que lhe dá isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Já tentou no arquivo insert.php fazer assim, para mim o arquivo js está correto

```
<?php
  var_dump($name = $_POST['nome']);
  var_dump($last_name = $_POST['sobrenome']);
```

Comment: Puts que falta de atenção! Poxa Obrigado Marcos!

Answer (score 1):

O Jquery esta funcionando corretamente (veja no [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tev5xe00/)), mas no PHP você esta dando var_dump apenas no `$_POST['nome']`, para ver todas faça assim:

**PHP:**

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

ou assim:

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Comment: Acabei realmente não vendo, obrigado pela resposta rápida!